# How to know if a point is inside a path?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a Path2D object that delimits an area :

let myRegion = new Path2D(...)

I need to know if a given point (x, y) is inside that area.

My thought was to do :

```
let x = 29,
    y = 34 // Sample point, in fact it isn't know at compile-time.

let ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d")
ctx.beginMath()
myRegion(ctx)
let isPointInside = ctx.isPointInPath(myRegion, x, y) // Here I don't really get why we don't have a myRegion.contains(x, y)
```

But it doesn't seem right to me to instantiate a new canvas just for that. Any idea ?

Thanks for reading !

Comment: You can use the ```isPointInPath()``` method of the ```CanvasRenderingContext2D``` interface to determine if a point is inside a Path2D object

Comment: Note that you have a typo in your snippet, `beginPath` not `beginMath`. (And it's anyway useless from a fresh context)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, a `Path2D` object is opaque, you can't read back any information from it directly, so it still makes perfect sense to have the `isPointInPath()` only defined on the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` interface since it's the only interface able to do something useful from that object.

You could make it a bit lighter by using an `OffscreenCanvas` though:

```js
const ctx = new OffscreenCanvas(0, 0).getContext("2d");
```

Note that we plan to make the `Path2D` interface less opaque in the future, and e.g. add methods to retrieve its path segments details, but even then, I suppose it would still be better to leave `isPointInPath` on the context only, at least for the parity with `isPointInStroke()` which does require the context's styles (`lineWidth`, etc.).